# calculate $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\cos(\sqrt{x+1})-\cos(\sqrt{x})$

Tags: real-analysis

To calculate $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\cos(\sqrt{x+1})-\cos(\sqrt{x})$ can I use prostaferesis formula?

Comment: Yes, you might, but then you also need to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt x=0$.

Comment: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\cos(\sqrt{x+1})-\cos(\sqrt{x})=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}2\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt x}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+1}}{2}\right)$$ 
$$=-\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt x}{2}\right)\cdot \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt x}{2}\right)}\cdot (\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt x)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it is not really necessary. By Lagrange's theorem
$$\cos(\sqrt{x+1})-\cos(\sqrt{x}) = -(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})\sin(\xi)=\frac{-\sin\xi}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1}},\qquad \xi\in(\sqrt{x},\sqrt{x+1})$$
hence the limit is clearly zero since $\cos'$ is bounded and $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1}\to +\infty$.

Comment: In the first line,  it must be
$\cos\left(\color{red}{\,\sqrt{\, x\,}\,}\right)$. Nice job.